# Check a type whether there is a specific style applied

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, xaml, styles

For unit testing I want to check whether a given type has a specific style applied. I already know that this type is derived from System.Windows.Window.
So I need a function like

```
bool HasMyStyle(Type theTypeToCheck)
{
  if( theTypeToCheck has my style applied )
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

The style is applied in app.xaml like so:

```
<Style TargetType="Window" x:Key="WindowBaseStyle">
  <Setter Property="Icon" Value="Resources/MyIcon.ico" />
  <Setter Property="ShowInTaskbar" Value="False" />
</Style>
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource WindowBaseStyle}" TargetType="local:AboutWindow" />
```

How can I check a type (in this case AboutWindow) if it has my style (WindowBaseStyle)?

Also it would be enough for me to check for the specific icon and the ShowInTaskbar property.

EDIT:

No need to answer this question anymore, because thanks to Phenix_yu I have a workaround now (Parsing app.xaml).

Comment: Did you try reading xaml file of your type directyly and check whether the style is applied in it?

Comment: No, I didn't think about that one. I was going the reflection way. But I will give it a try.